# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory - Related to Appium

Tags: maven, appium

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.<clinit>(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:57)
    at BaseTest.globalSetup(basetest.java:14)
    at androidtest.globalSetup(androidtest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:317)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 21 more
```

Below is what i have where the code fails at globalSetUp()
[image]

Below is also relevant code
[image]

and Appium server says
[image]

Hello all, trying to get appium working for the first time as a novice, would like to know what i can do over at pom.xml or what can i do to resolve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a SLF4J implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
```